# Hibernate - ensure that all entities are persisted or none?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, transactions, ejb

I have the following code to persist two different `entities` to my `MYSQL` DB.

This works as expected, however if there is an issue with one table and not the other then one table is getting populated, and the other not.

Note - I am running my application as an `EAR` file within a `jboss EAP` server.

I want to ensure that either **both** tables are populated or **none**.

How can I do so?

**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="entitystore" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/datasources/global</jta-data-source>
```

**Java service class:**

```
public void createCompanyStatuses(String client, CompanyStatusPostDTO companyStatusPostDTO) {

        EntityManager entityManager = null;

        try {

            CompanyStatus companyStatus = new CompanyStatus();
            companyStatus.setCompanyLabel(candidateMaskedStatusPostDTO.getCompanyLabel());

            entityManager = entityManagement.createEntityManager(client);
            entityManager.persist(companyStatus);

            for(Integer employeeStatusId: companyStatusPostDTO.getEmployeeStatuses()){

                CompanyStatusEmployeeStatus companyStatusEmployeeStatus = new CompanyStatusEmployeeStatus();
                companyStatusEmployeeStatus.setEmployeeId(employeeStatusId);
                companyStatusEmployeeStatus.setCompanyId(companyStatus.getCompanyId()); //todo - how will get this?
                entityManager.persist(CompanyStatusEmployeeStatus);
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error("An exception has occurred in inserting data into the table" + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            entityManagement.closeEntityManager(client, entityManager);
        }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have tried adding:

```
 @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

However, the issue still remains that the successful persists work and the non-successful don't - rather that all or nothing being persisted.

Comment: With transactions?

Comment: @Shadow can you please show an example, I am only learning hibernate currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a transaction.

With spring use the @Transactional annotation.

Without spring framework, you can do

```
doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    ...
    entityManager.persist(obj);
    ...
});
```

see : https://vladmihalcea.com/high-performance-java-persistence-github-repository/

Comment: OP has already EJB and JTA available. He's just most probably not using them correctly. Telling the OP to use Spring instead of explaining the correct way makes no sense.